# ошибка при запуске кода Python (Делал веб дизайн для приложения в python)

Tags: python, windows, eel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chinu\Desktop\main.py", line 9, in <module>
eel.start("main.html",port = 0, size = (400, 600), mode = 'custom')
  File "C:\Users\chinu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 174, in start
    show(*start_urls)
  File "C:\Users\chinu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 206, in show
     brw.open(list(start_urls), _start_args)
  File "C:\Users\chinu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\eel\browsers.py", line 63, in open
     sps.Popen(options['cmdline_args'],
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
```

Вот код

```
import eel

eel.init("web")

eel.start("main.html",port = 0, size = (400, 600), mode = 'custom')
```

Comment: Имя компьютера какое?

Comment: DESKTOP-GHL2D5M